# jconfirm plugin Ok and cancel button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

jconfirm plugin when i use mouse it return actual value i.e true or false on pressing OK or Cancel button but when i use tab key and have focus on cancel and then press Enter key it actually treat it as OK now how to stop this.I have an idea to use keypress event for enter key but it is not user friendly so tell me any solution.

Comment: i had find that in jquery.alert.js file u need to comment out two lines Written in switch case for confirm plugin i.e
case 'confirm':
          $("#popup_ok").focus();
     $("#popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
      //if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
      //if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
     });
    break

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug in the plugin - [this code](https://github.com/riggerthegeek/jConfirm/blob/master/jquery.jconfirm-1.0.js):

```
/* Attach the events */
jQuery('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 27) {
        /* Escape */
        jQuery('#'+objConfig.cancelTrigger).trigger('click');
        return false;
    } else if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        /* Enter */
        jQuery('#'+objConfig.confirmTrigger).trigger('click');
        return false;
    } else {
        /* Any other key */
        return true;
    }
});
```

Looks like it assumes escape is always cancel and enter is always confirm, regardless of what button is highlighted.